# nodejs timeout for async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await, settimeout

I'm having issues with await calls to async functions.  Something is preventing them from completing and they are building up on the event loop. I know I should find the exact issue and fix it, but for now I'd like to embed a kill switch in the functions so the self destruct after a period of time.  I'll log when it happens to make it easier to find the problem functions.

I tried using setTimeout to throw and error but that just causes an uncaught exception.

I have googled this for hours and can't find a good solution, but I know may developers are trying to find a solution.

This is happening in some massive nodejs Express REST APIs so digging through the code is extremely difficult.

Do you have one?

TIA

Comment: It would be helpful to see the relevant code; perhaps a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried with `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'stackup' module - it will print stacktraces of your uncaught exceptions, and hopefully reveal your issue.

[Stackup on Github](https://github.com/groundwater/node-stackup)